# Concatenating row values with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I want to concatenate a row who have the same src_Refname value ! like in the picture

[image]

and get like this :

[image]

is there any easy way to do it ?

[image]

on using the tool described in the link, i try to copy (see the picture)

1. "NordCp" on "n"
2. "SudCp"  on "s"
3. "EstCp"  on "e"
4. "Ouest"  on "o"

but the tool works just for "EstCp" and for the others it gives me a emplty field !

Comment: it's a single table, on the first picture i just turned off the other tabls !

Comment: Can you add a screen capture of your attempted field calculator python script to your question?

Comment: you can see it here [link](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=52dfcef46fdb4c76bfbc08dc01570f3c) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With python, all things are possible.

In arcpy a `cursor` is used to read a table, row by row. You can use what is called a `SearchCursor` to read through a feature table and pull the relevant information. You can then perform a second cursor - an `UpdateCursor` - to update the table with the data in the form you want. You will also want a few python `Dictionaries` to store values.

Here's what you do:

Open up a new session of ArcMap and add only the feature class you want to update to your table of contents. For example, here I've added "TestFC":

[image: Adding feature class]

The attribute table maybe looks something like this:

[image: Feature class attribute table]

Next, click the Python button:

[image: Python]

Copy the following text into the python shell that pops up:

```
#Import all functions from arcpy
from arcpy import *

#Name of layer
#!!Change me as needed
Layer = "TestFC"

#Fields to check
#!!Change me as needed too
SCfields = ["src_RefName", "North", "South", "East", "West"]
UCfields = ["src_RefName", "n", "s", "e", "w"]

#Create empty dictionaries
Ndi = {}
Sdi = {}
Edi = {}
Wdi = {}

#create SearchCursor object
cursor = da.SearchCursor (Layer, SCfields)
#Iterate through rows
for row in cursor:
    #Dictionary logic tree
    if row[1]:
        if not row[0] in Ndi:
            Ndi[row[0]] = [row[1]]
        else:
            Ndi[row[0]].append(row[1])
    if row[2]:
        if not row[0] in Sdi:
            Sdi[row[0]] = [row[2]]
        else:
            Sdi[row[0]].append(row[2])
    if row[3]:
        if not row[0] in Edi:
            Edi[row[0]] = [row[3]]
        else:
            Edi[row[0]].append(row[3])
    if row[4]:
        if not row[0] in Wdi:
            Wdi[row[0]] = [row[4]]
        else:
            Wdi[row[0]].append(row[4])

del cursor

#create UpdateCursor
cursor = da.UpdateCursor (Layer, UCfields)
#Iterate through rows
for row in cursor:
    #Update logic tree
    if row[0] in Ndi:
        row[1] = ",".join(map(str, Ndi[row[0]]))
    if row[0] in Sdi:
        row[2] = ",".join(map(str, Sdi[row[0]]))
    if row[0] in Edi:
        row[3] = ",".join(map(str, Edi[row[0]]))
    if row[0] in Wdi:
        row[4] = ",".join(map(str, Wdi[row[0]]))
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor
print "Done"
```

You will need to change the line `Layer = "TestFC"`. Change `TestFC` to the name of the layer in your table of contents.

Also:

```
SCfields = ["src_RefName", "North", "South", "East", "West"]
UCfields = ["src_RefName", "n", "s", "e", "w"]
```

This indicates the fields you wish to search for SCfields, and the fields you wish to populate for UCfields, along with the reference field to start. Make sure the update fields are TEXT fields.

After you've copied this code, with whatever needed changes made, hit enter and wait for "Done" to pop up.

Go back to your attribute table and Reload Cache:

[image: Reload Cache]

**Voila:**

[image]

Here's the code for just a single field, to make it easy.

```
#Import all functions from arcpy
from arcpy import *

#Name of layer
#!!Change me as needed
Layer = "TestFC"

#Fields to check
#!!Change me as needed too
SCfields = ["src_RefName", "North"]
UCfields = ["src_RefName", "n"]

#Create empty dictionaries
Ndi = {}

#create SearchCursor object
cursor = da.SearchCursor (Layer, SCfields)
#Iterate through rows
for row in cursor:
    #Dictionary logic tree
    if row[1]:
        if not row[0] in Ndi:
            Ndi[row[0]] = [row[1]]
        else:
            Ndi[row[0]].append(row[1])
del cursor

#create UpdateCursor
cursor = da.UpdateCursor (Layer, UCfields)
#Iterate through rows
for row in cursor:
    #Update logic tree
    if row[0] in Ndi:
        row[1] = ",".join(map(str, Ndi[row[0]]))
del cursor
print "Done"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Concatenate Row Value Geoprocessing Sample by shitijmehta](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=52dfcef46fdb4c76bfbc08dc01570f3c). I have used it before and it works well. Read through the description of the tool. It tells you that it will retain all rows after concatenating, so you can use the 'delete identical' tool to remove identical rows.

Comment: Hi Tangnar, thank you for responding, i saw it but it takes in consideration just a feature class, while i need to work with tables !

Comment: +1 This tool does exactly what the OP is looking for.  @user30896, I just tested the tool with a dBASE table and it worked fine.

Comment: oh yes it works, i really don't know what was wrong with... thank you..

Comment: Aaron i get the copy field empty !!

Comment: i edit my question plz se the change